# Most performant way to add array item to serialized array column in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

In my Rails 6 app I have the following two models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  serialize :unread_news_item_ids, Array

end
```

---

```
class NewsItem < ApplicationRecord

  after_create :inform_users

private

  def inform_users
    User.all.each do |user|
      user.unread_news_item_ids << id
      user.save(:validate => false)
    end
  end

end
```

---

Whenever I (the "Admin") create a new `NewsItem` I want my users to be notified about it, so I am tracking the `unread_news_items_ids` in a [serialized](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) column my `Users` table.

The code above works, however it puts a heavy workload on the database as it saves every user *separately*.

Is there a more performant way to achieve this?

I was thinking about something along the lines of [update_all](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) but that won't work with serialized database columns I suppose (?).

Comment: Create a separate `UnreadNews(belongs_to: user, belongs_to: news)` table with proper indexes. Serialized array will not scale very well at all

Comment: My recommendation would be to create an intermediary model maybe something like `UserNewsItems` that joins `User` and `NewsItem` and has a read column then `unread` just becomes a scope

Comment: OK, thanks but won't that be too many table rows in the long run? (One NewsItem will create one row for each User...)

Comment: Lots of rows in a narrow table aren't a problem, an ever growing blob of YAML is a problem. You're better off forgetting that `serialize` exists and sticking to properly normalized tables, relational databases are really good at working with tables.

Comment: @Tintin81 on second though you could use `UserReadNewsItems` instead and then the inverse scope would result in Unread News Items. This way you only add records when a User "reads" a News Item.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I decided to go with your suggestions and created a join table `ReadNewsItems` which worked pretty well. I posted a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70275349).