# How to eliminate N+1 queries from database query in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails 6 app I have these models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :read_news_items
  has_many :news_items, :through => :read_news_items

end
```

---

```
class NewsItem < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :read_news_items
  has_many :users, :through => :read_news_items

  def read?(user)
    read_news_items.where(:user_id => user.id).any?
  end

end
```

---

```
class ReadNewsItem < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :news_item

end
```

---

In my controller action I want to list all news items and highlight the ones that have not yet been read by the user:

```
class NewsItemsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @news_items = NewsItem.all
  end

end
```

The problem is that this generates N+1 queries for each record because the `read?(current_user)` gets called for each `user` record.

How can this problem be overcome?

I tried appending `includes(:read_news_items)` and `joins(:read_news_items)` to the database query in my controller but to no avail.

Comment: How is the read?(current_user) is getting called?

Comment: And what query are you trying to run. Can you share the logs

Comment: How about next: `@news_items = NewsItem.where.not(id: @user. read_news_items.pluck(:new_items_id)`? and you don't need to call `read?` in the view.

Comment: What @kunashir said except you shouldn't call `pluck`, use `select` instead. `select` will create a IN clause with a subquery; `pluck` will create an IN clause with a disposable `Array`

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
class NewsItem < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :read_news_items

  def read?(user)
    if read_news_items.loaded?
      read_news_items.any? {|rni| rni.user_id == user.id }
    else
      read_news_items.where(:user_id => user.id).any?
    end
  end
end

class NewsItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @news_items = NewsItem.includes(:read_news_items).all
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the `loaded?` method.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I learned something from every answer that was given here. So thanks for that.

I changed my `read?` method to the following which seems to have eliminated the N+1 queries:

```
class NewsItem < ApplicationRecord

  def read?(user)
    user.read_news_items.pluck(:news_item_id).include?(id)
  end

end
```

Comment: The parentheses around `user.read_news_items.pluck` are not needed.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my code.